# Census transform in python openCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am starting to work with openCV and python in a project related with stereovision. I found this page of documentation about the Census Transform in C++ with openCV.
[link](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/d7f/namespacecv_1_1stereo.html#a939dfbb1a0d1a3255749629343247bd5)

Does anyone know if there are similar functions for python implementation?

(e.g. cv2.nameofthefunction)

Thank you all!

EDIT: the excellent solution of PM 2Ring (thank you again) can work with openCV with this little change: instead of using Image.open

```
img = cv2.imread(img.png)
#some minor changes I needed like select some ROI and store them in img2[j] 
#then a for cycle in which I wrote
src_img = img2[j] 
h, w = src_img.shape
```

where the "shape" instruction seems to switch the order of w and h compared to "size" command. Then I paste the rest of the code of PM 2Ring and it worked wonderfully

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't use openCV, and I don't know if there's an existing implementation of the Census Transform. However, it's easy enough to implement using Numpy.

Here's a simple demo that uses [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.x/index.html) to handle loading the image and converting the array data back to an image.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' The Census Transform

    Scan an 8 bit greyscale image with a 3x3 window
    At each scan position create an 8 bit number by comparing the value
    of the centre pixel in the 3x3 window with that of its 8 neighbours.
    The bit is set to 1 if the outer pixel >= the centre pixel

    See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38265364/census-transform-in-python-opencv

    Written by PM 2Ring 2016.07.09
'''

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

iname = 'Glasses0S.png'
oname = 'Glasses0S_census.png'

#Get the source image
src_img = Image.open(iname)
src_img.show()

w, h = src_img.size
print('image size: %d x %d = %d' % (w, h, w * h))
print('image mode:', src_img.mode)

#Convert image to Numpy array
src_bytes = np.asarray(src_img)

#Initialize output array
census = np.zeros((h-2, w-2), dtype='uint8')

#centre pixels, which are offset by (1, 1)
cp = src_bytes[1:h-1, 1:w-1]

#offsets of non-central pixels 
offsets = [(u, v) for v in range(3) for u in range(3) if not u == 1 == v]

#Do the pixel comparisons
for u,v in offsets:
    census = (census << 1) | (src_bytes[v:v+h-2, u:u+w-2] >= cp)

#Convert transformed data to image
out_img = Image.fromarray(census)
out_img.show()
out_img.save(oname)
```

**source**

[image: source image]

**output**

[image: output image]

The original full-colour Glasses image was created by Gilles Tran using POV-Ray, and is in the public domain. It may be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POV-Ray#/media/File:Glasses_800_edit.png).

Comment: Dear PM, I am not very familiar nor with Python neither with Stack Overflow... Answer accepted! I did some test (because i have to use opencv in the rest of the script and I found a way to include your solution)

Comment: @marcoresk Excellent! I just did a quick Google search and found that OpenCV has some Hamming distance functions, so it should be pretty easy to get the Hamming distance between the Census transforms of a stereo pair. Of course, it's pretty easy to do that using Numpy as well.

Comment: This will be my next (serious) try but it works fine even with using the stereo algorithm (SGBM) from openCV as if the census images were the real stereo pair!

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 code using numpy and OpenCV. Adds the ability to handle different window sizes and generate cost differences between stereo images. Example of transformation shown below on [Middlebury 2014 stereo image set](http://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/data/scenes2014/) (Playroom-perfect).

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def transform(image, window_size=3):
    """
    Take a gray scale image and for each pixel around the center of the window generate a bit value of length
    window_size * 2 - 1. window_size of 3 produces bit length of 8, and 5 produces 24.

    The image gets border of zero padded pixels half the window size.

    Bits are set to one if pixel under consideration is greater than the center, otherwise zero.

    :param image: numpy.ndarray(shape=(MxN), dtype=numpy.uint8)
    :param window_size: int odd-valued
    :return: numpy.ndarray(shape=(MxN), , dtype=numpy.uint8)
    >>> image = np.array([ [50, 70, 80], [90, 100, 110], [60, 120, 150] ])
    >>> np.binary_repr(transform(image)[0, 0])
    '1011'
    >>> image = np.array([ [60, 75, 85], [115, 110, 105], [70, 130, 170] ])
    >>> np.binary_repr(transform(image)[0, 0])
    '10011'
    """
    half_window_size = window_size // 2

    image = cv2.copyMakeBorder(image, top=half_window_size, left=half_window_size, right=half_window_size, bottom=half_window_size, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=0)
    rows, cols = image.shape
    census = np.zeros((rows - half_window_size * 2, cols - half_window_size * 2), dtype=np.uint8)
    center_pixels = image[half_window_size:rows - half_window_size, half_window_size:cols - half_window_size]

    offsets = [(row, col) for row in range(half_window_size) for col in range(half_window_size) if not row == half_window_size + 1 == col]
    for (row, col) in offsets:
        census = (census << 1) | (image[row:row + rows - half_window_size * 2, col:col + cols - half_window_size * 2] >= center_pixels)
    return census

def column_cost(left_col, right_col):
    """
    Column-wise Hamming edit distance
    Also see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxsvG4sSuvA&feature=youtu.be&t=1032
    :param left: numpy.ndarray(shape(Mx1), dtype=numpy.uint)
    :param right: numpy.ndarray(shape(Mx1), dtype=numpy.uint)
    :return: numpy.ndarray(shape(Mx1), dtype=numpy.uint)
    >>> image = np.array([ [50, 70, 80], [90, 100, 110], [60, 120, 150] ])
    >>> left = transform(image)
    >>> image = np.array([ [60, 75, 85], [115, 110, 105], [70, 130, 170] ])
    >>> right = transform(image)
    >>> column_cost(left, right)[0, 0]
    2
    """
    return np.sum(np.unpackbits(np.bitwise_xor(left_col, right_col), axis=1), axis=1).reshape(left_col.shape[0], left_col.shape[1])

def cost(left, right, window_size=3, disparity=0):
    """
    Compute cost difference between left and right grayscale images. Disparity value can be used to assist with evaluating stereo
    correspondence.
    :param left: numpy.ndarray(shape=(MxN), dtype=numpy.uint8)
    :param right: numpy.ndarray(shape=(MxN), dtype=numpy.uint8)
    :param window_size: int odd-valued
    :param disparity: int
    :return:
    """
    ct_left = transform(left, window_size=window_size)
    ct_right = transform(right, window_size=window_size)
    rows, cols = ct_left.shape
    C = np.full(shape=(rows, cols), fill_value=0)
    for col in range(disparity, cols):
        C[:, col] = column_cost(
            ct_left[:, col:col + 1],
            ct_right[:, col - disparity:col - disparity + 1]
        ).reshape(ct_left.shape[0])
    return C

def norm(image):
    return cv2.normalize(image, dst=None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX).astype(np.uint8)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Image set from http://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/data/scenes2014/
    resize_pct = 0.1
    ndisp = 330 # from calib.txt
    ndisp *= resize_pct
    # load as grayscale
    left = cv2.imread('Playroom-perfect-left.png', 0)
    right = cv2.imread('Playroom-perfect-right.png', 0)
    left = cv2.resize(left, dsize=(0,0), fx=resize_pct, fy=resize_pct)
    right = cv2.resize(right, dsize=(0, 0), fx=resize_pct, fy=resize_pct)

    window_size = 5
    ct_left = norm(transform(left, window_size))
    ct_right = norm(transform(right, window_size))

    ct_costs = []
    for exponent in range(0, 6):
        import math
        disparity = int(ndisp / math.pow(2, exponent))
        print(math.pow(2, exponent), disparity)
        ct_costs.append(norm(cost(left, right, window_size, disparity)))

    cv2.imshow('left/right grayscale/census', np.vstack([np.hstack([left, right]), np.hstack([ct_left, ct_right])]))
    cv2.imshow('costs', np.vstack(ct_costs))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```