# How to Implement a Census Transform in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, binary, filtering

I want to perform a Census transform in MATLAB at the center pixels of each filter's window as shown below:
[image: Census Transform Explained]

If the the image does not appear, an alternative link: https://i.ibb.co/9Y6LfSL/Shared-Screenshot.jpg

My Initial attempt for the code is:

```
function output =census(img,census_size)
img_gray = rgb2gray(img);
[y,x]=size(img_gray);          
borders = floor(census_size/2); % limit to exclude image borders when filtering

for(iy = 1+borders : y-borders)
    for(ix = 1+borders : x-borders)
        f=img_gray(iy-borders:iy+borders,ix-borders:ix+borders);
        iix=ix-borders;
        iiy=iy-borders;
     %   shift=bitsll(img_out(iiy,iix),1);
        img_out(iiy,iix)= % Must be Implemented with census

    end
end
%normalised_image = img_out ./ max(max(img_out)) ;
output=img_out;
imshow(normalised_image);

end
```

iix and iiy at the second for loop represents my current location for the center pixels. f is my current filter window.

In addition to comparsion operation with the window's other pixels, I need to set each comparsion result to logical 1/0, and extend the total result ( by shifting I guess) to 8-bit data, then convert this binary number to a deciaml number. How I can do this in a practical way in MATLAB?
I have checked this in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38269363/12173333

But could not make a similarity in MATLAB.

Comment: The naive approach is adding another 2 loops inside your 2 loops, for the neighbours of our pixel. Try that, then you can start thinking about pratical/fast ways

Comment: I think I can do that, I could form the new logical window resulting from comparing the center pixel with  the neighbors. I am thinking now how can I extend my binary result by left shifting starting from the lowest row, omitting the center pixel, and setting the center pixel's values. 
For example if my logical array is [ 1 0 0; 0 center 1 ; 1 1 0] my center should be equal to uint8(0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the image processing toolbox you can use [blockproc](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html):

```
%Load your image
I = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oxaQ.png');

%Creation of the census transform function
fun = @(B) [128 64 32 16 0 8 4 2 1]*(B.data(:)>B.data(2,2));

%Process the image, block-by-block with overlap, force the result to be of type uint8
I2 = uint8(blockproc(I.',[1 1],fun,'BorderSize',[1,1],'TrimBorder',0)).'
```

Here `blockproc` is configured for a 3x3 windows (with overlap) and work for grayscale image. The function `fun` check which part of the block is strictly bigger than the center of the block. We obtain a `1x9` logical vector. Then I multiply this vector with `[128 64 32 16 0 8 4 2 1]` (binary to decimal transformation).

**Update:**

Optimisation with linear algeabra

For random windows size you can use:

```
I = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oxaQ.png');

w   = 5;                                              % windows size, any odd number between 3 and 31.
b2d = 2.^[w^2-1:-1:ceil(w^2/2),0,floor(w^2/2):-1:1]   % binary to decimal vector
cen = ceil(w/2);                                      % center position

%Creation of the census transform function
fun = @(B) b2d*(B.data(:)>B.data(cen,cen));

%Process the image, block-by-block with overlap
I2 = blockproc(I.',[1 1],fun,'BorderSize',[cen-1,cen-1],'TrimBorder',0).'/sum(b2d)
```

**Input:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! If I use bigger window size, I should change the center as (floor(row/2) + 1, floor(col/2) + 1) ?, moreover, don't you think it's better that I normalize the output transformed image for better calculating the hamming  (based on 0 or 1 pixel values) distance for matching block algorithms in Image Depth?

Comment: Check my edit where the windows size can be choosen and the output is normalized. The windows size should always be odd. And noticed that with, for example, a window size = 7, the algorithm already deal with value of magnitude 2^(7^2-1) or 2^48. If the window size is too big you will get an overflow.

Comment: In theory, the maximum window size could be 31.